# $F$ continuous, but not uniformly cont.,$ f_n$ uniformly convergent. Find $g_n:=F \circ f_n$ such that $g_n$ is not uniformly convergent.

Tags: analysis

Let $$I \subset \mathbb{R}$$ $$f_n: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ $$F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

I have proven that if $F$ is uniformly continuous and $f_n$ is uniformly convergent, then $F \circ f_n$ is uniformly convergent.

I cannot however find an example where $F$ violates the conditions and $f_n$ does not, such that $F \circ f_n$ is not uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I= \mathbb R$, $F(x)=x^2$ and $f_n(x)=x+\frac{1}{n}$. Then $(f_n) $ converges uniformly to $f(x)=x$, but

$g_n(x)=F(f_n(x))=x^2+2x \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges only pointwise to $x^2$, since

$|g_n(x)-x^2|=|2x \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}|$ and $|g_n(n)-n^2|=2+\frac{1}{n^2}$.